# Java Making A Checkerboard GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to draw out a checkerboard GUI but I am having some issues with it.

I have the frame and the layout already set, I need someones help with the logic to make the checkerboard alternate the appropriate colors.

This is the frame:

```
    JFrame checkerBoard = new JFrame(); 
    checkerBoard.setSize(400, 400); 
    checkerBoard.setVisible(true);
    checkerBoard.setTitle("CheckerBoard"); 
    checkerBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    int row = 8; 
    int col = 8; 

    Container pane = checkerBoard.getContentPane(); 
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
```

Can someone please help me with the logic to create the checkerboard pattern using 64 JPanels? Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to try something first.

Comment: Maybe look into setting the background color of the panel. First focus on getting all the panels visible in your frame, then try setting them all as black and then when you can do that try and figure out the alternating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SquarePanel extends JPanel{
    Color color = Color.BLACK;
    static boolean isRed = false;

    public SquarePanel(){
        if (isRed){
            color = Color.BLACK;
            isRed = false;
        } else {
            color = Color.RED;
            isRed = true;
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeigth());
    }
}
```

You can use this panel to alternate square colors. Everytime You create a `new SquarePanel()`, it will alternate colors from red to black or black to red. You can also use this panel to paint on the pieces. Just call it 64 times in your current code

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of modulo? Try using that with the row/column number. Google it.